# Update package.json version working with Jenkins & GitLab

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, npm, versioning

I have a project that is hosted in Gitlab. I have a Webhook hook which tells Jenkins to trigger a CI build when someone pushes code to the master.  I plan to use `npm version` to update the package.json.  How do I get the new version commited into git without triggering another CI build